# haml with markdown claims rdiscount not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml, markdown, rdiscount

I've specified

```
gem 'haml'
gem 'rdiscount'
```

in my Gemfile and ran bundle install

The relevant code is

```
.welcome-message
  :markdown
    Welcome **#{current_user.email}**
```

When I access the page I get

> Can't run Markdown filter; required
>   'rdiscount' or 'peg_markdown' or
>   'maruku' or 'bluecloth', but none were
>   found

I'm using rails 3.0.5, what am I missing?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Turns out I'm an idiot. All that was needed was to restart the server. Carry on everyone.

Comment: Yeah, got same problem with gem recently, reinstalled it 5 times before restarting the server :)

Comment: @vadim I keep remembering and forgetting, and you reminded me again :)

Comment: Turns out there are at least nine other idiots out there. Honored to be part of the club!

Comment: Working in IT support apparently taught me nothing. I have StackOverflow open faster than I can say _"try turning it off and on again"_.