# Haml + Markdown not working

Tags: ruby, haml, markdown

I'm new to Haml and discovered that I can use Markdown for my content, however whenever I try to use Markdown in my Haml, I get this error:

```
Haml::Error at /
Can't run Markdown filter; required 'rdiscount' or 'peg_markdown' or 'maruku' or 'bluecloth', but none were found
```

I found this question:
[haml with markdown claims rdiscount not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5424504/haml-with-markdown-claims-rdiscount-not-found), however, this didn't work for me. I'm using the excellent [Fire.app](http://fireapp.handlino.com) as the watcher/compiler/server, and I've created a Gemfile with (and run bundle install):

```
gem 'rdiscount' # Markdown
gem 'RedCloth'  # Textile
```

So I'm stumped. I've reset the Fire.app, and even my machine, but but I just can't make this error go away.

I'm on a Mac OS X 10.8.2, ruby ruby 1.8.7, rdiscount 1.6.8, haml 3.1.7, and I'm not using rails.

Any ideas?

*** UPDATE 1 ***
Executing haml from the command-line works :| The markdown is handled as expected, which means there must be something wrong with Fire.app. I'll keep investigating...

*** UPDATE 2 ***
I filed a bug report, and it looks like it's been fixed (Fingers crossed...): https://github.com/handlino/FireApp/issues/66

*** UPDATE 3 ***
Yep, I can confirm the new version of Fire.app (as yet unreleased) works :)

Comment: Fire.app uses Java and JRuby and looks like it contains [it’s own version of various Ruby libraries](https://github.com/handlino/FireApp/tree/1.3/lib/ruby/common), including Haml and Kramdown for Markdown support, but not one of the Markdown engines used by Haml. I don’t know if it’s possible to add libraries/gems to Fire.app.

Comment: Hi, you're right but apparently they've already fixed the bug, it's just not public yet. I'm getting a new version now to try, and I'll post my results.